# how to fix page header+table header and scroll table body and page footer with page scroll

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to fix the header of page with the table header on top, and make the rest of page and the table body to move with the page scroll.

I reached a working solution where it almost do what is supposed, by duplicating the table header into the fixed top, and make a div sliding below the fixed div on top, however the body columns are not always aligned with header and with the same size. When zooming in and out, it doesnt work very well: some times both headers are visible, or overlapped.

```js
//IE 9 compatible
var header = document.getElementById("zmyHeader");
var divResults = document.getElementById("divResults");

var h = header.getBoundingClientRect().bottom - header.getBoundingClientRect().top;

var divheadertbl = document.getElementById("headerResultTblFixedDiv");
if (divheadertbl) {
  var hdivheadertbl = divheadertbl.getBoundingClientRect().bottom - divheadertbl.getBoundingClientRect().top;
  divResults.style.paddingTop = (h - hdivheadertbl - 5) + "px";
}
window.onscroll = function() {
  myFunction()
};

function myFunction() {
  var Y = document.body.scrollLeft;
  var j = Y;
  var supportPageOffset = window.pageXOffset !== undefined;
  var isCSS1Compat = ((document.compatMode || "") === "CSS1Compat");

  var x = supportPageOffset ? window.pageXOffset : isCSS1Compat ? document.documentElement.scrollLeft : document.body.scrollLeft;
  document.getElementById("zmyHeader").style.marginLeft = -x + "px";
}
```

```css
.sticky {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  align: center;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<div ID="zmyHeader" class="sticky">
  ...
  <div id="headerResultTblFixedDiv">
    <table id="headerResultTblFixed">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>Col1Head</th>
          <th>Col2Head</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>
<div id="divResults" style="padding:0px;width:100%">
  <!---div resultados-->
  <table id="resultsTable" width="967" border="0" align="center" cellpadding="2" cellspacing="0" bgcolor="white">
    </tr>
    <td></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

Below, a picture of the expected result:
[image: Picture of the expected result]

Comment: You got a typo at the start of your `<tr>`, maybe that will help.

Comment: Have you tried using CSS: `#headerResultTblFixedDiv { position: fixed; top: 0;}`?

Answer (score 0):

Try out this code.I have not used javascript.Just used html and css.And rather than using table heading i have used simple paragraph tags , you can use heading tags too.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<style>
    *{
        box-sizing: border-box;
    }
    header h1{      
        top: -20px;
        text-align: center;
        background-color: aquamarine;
        padding: 80px;
        position: fixed;
        min-width: 100%;
    } 
    main{
        position: fixed;
        min-width: 100%;
        clear: both;
        margin-top:-79px ;
    }
    main div {
        min-width:100%; 
        margin-left: 5px;
        margin-bottom: -150px;
    }
    main p{
        float:left;
        min-width: 33%;
        text-align: center;
        border: 1px solid ;
        padding: 20px;      
        background-color: aquamarine
    }
    footer h1{
        margin-top: 50px;
        text-align: center;
        background-color: aquamarine;
        padding: 80px;
        min-width: 100%;
    }
    section{
        clear:both;

    }
     table  {
        border: 1px solid blue;
        min-width: 100%;
         clear: both;
         margin-top: 250px;
    }
    tr td{
        border: 1px solid blue;
        padding: 10px;
    }   

    </style>
</head>

<body>
<section>
<header>
    <h1>This Is Header</h1> 
</header>

    <main>
    <div>
    <p>Header 1</p><p>Header 1</p><p>Header 1</p>
    </div>
    </main>
</section>

    <section>
        <table>
         <tr><td>Table Data 1</td><td>Table Data 2</td><td>Table Data 3</td></tr>
        <tr><td>Table Data 3</td><td>Table Data 4</td><td>Table Data 3</td></tr>
         <tr><td>Table Data 1</td><td>Table Data 2</td><td>Table Data 3</td></tr>
        <tr><td>Table Data 3</td><td>Table Data 4</td><td>Table Data 3</td></tr>
        <tr><td>Table Data 1</td><td>Table Data 2</td><td>Table Data 3</td></tr>
        <tr><td>Table Data 3</td><td>Table Data 4</td><td>Table Data 3</td></tr>
         <tr><td>Table Data 1</td><td>Table Data 2</td><td>Table Data 3</td></tr>
        <tr><td>Table Data 3</td><td>Table Data 4</td><td>Table Data 3</td></tr>

        </table>
    </section>  

    <footer>        
        <h1>This Is footer</h1> 
    </footer>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hi. thanks for replying. That solution has the same problem as my own.
It doesn't properly align the columns with the headers.